# Updating an entity object with relation to another table-object (NxN) (Inserting, deleting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity

Using entity for a table with NxN-relation (to another table), I can´t update the first table object (with its second table inside it) because the program show an exception message related with the second table and it says there is a record with the same PK in the second table (but I am not updating the second table per se, I am updating the NxN-table which means the relations between the two tables).

This is the scenario:

**TABLE1 - EntityObject1**

*Attribute1*        int

*Attribute2*        string

*Attribute3*     string

*Attribute4*     List(EntityObject2)

**TABLE2 - EntityObject2**

*Attribute1*     int

*Attribute2*     string

---

So:

```
var previous = context.TABLE1.Include(path => path.TABLE2)
      .Where(p => p.Attribute1 == updateElement.Attribute1).FirstOrDefault();
previous.Attribute4 = updateElement.Attribute4;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Not working as I said.

Another approach tried was:

> **First** - Remove previous from the context, and Save context.
>
> **Second** - Add the updateElement and Save context (not taking care about the fact of the PK´s changes)

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Completely lost... Thanks you mates.

Comment: Could you please post the actual class definitions for Table1 & Table2.  In your generic example, the INCLUDE would reference the name of the List<Table2> and not Table2 directly.  Also Attribute1 = update will fail, requires ==

Comment: @JohnWhite  First one - it is because it is like that. Attribute 4 is a list of object of Table2 (I am using entity, you should check the tag of my question). Second one - Really man? That has not sense. I am not comparing object... C´Mon... Anyway, thanks for your response fellow...

Comment: p => p.Attribute1 = updateElement.Attribute1 is a comparison iirc

Comment: On your first point, List(Table2) is named Table2 as well?  Ok

Comment: @JohnWhite Dont be a child... Thanks it was my fault. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally find it. I am posting the idea for helping others to achieve it, at least, using this way:

Note: We must to use transaction for handling the operation in one step.

**For inserting**

I generate the object - Table 1 as usual and for attribute 4, I generate a list of object - Table 2 (attaching first), then I asign list to attribute 4...

```
(using context = new Dbcontext())
{
  using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
  {
    Table1 object1 = new Table1
    {
      Attribute1 = 1, //(autoincrement really)
      Attribute2 = "random value",
      Attribute3 = "random value",
    };

    foreach (Table2 obj2 in NewValues)
    {
      Table2 o = new Table2() {Attribute1 = obj2.int, Attribute2 = obj2.string};
      context.Table2.Attach(o);
      object1.Attribute4.Add(o);
    }
  }
}
```

**For updating**

I just erase, for inserting later.

---

Another way for the inserting:

Store List in a temp List
Adding Object1 without Attribute4 to the context.
For finally, add temp List to object1.Attribute4.

```
(using context = new Dbcontext())
{
  using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
  {
    Table1 object1 = new Table1
    {
      Attribute1 = 1, //(autoincrement really)
      Attribute2 = "random value",
      Attribute3 = "random value",
    };

    List<Table2> tempTable2 = new List<Object2>();
    foreach (Table2 obj2 in NewValues)
    {
      Table2 o = new Table2() {Attribute1 = obj2.int, Attribute2 = obj2.string};
      tempTable2.Add(o);
    }

    context.Table1.Add(object1);
    context.SavesChanges();

    Table1 object11 = context.Table1.First(o => o.Attribute1 == object1.Attribute1);
    object11.Attribute4 = tempTable2
    context.SavesChanges();
  }
}
```